# Вызов методов объекта

Tags: php, ооп

Скажите пожалуйста, как реализовать подобный вызов методов для объекта:

```
$request = $request
    ->withMethod('OPTIONS')
    ->withRequestTarget('*')
    ->withUri(new Uri('https://example.org/'));
```

Должна ли каждая функция возвращать объект-экземпляр класса?
P.S. подобную реализацию встречал в Yii2.

Comment: Ну да, возвращаешь сам объект в методе и все, но так лучше делать лишь с определенно нацеленными объектами. Где удобнее всего делать `лапшу`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

То, что вы приводите в качестве примера, часто называют шаблоном проектирования [*Текучий интерфейс*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) (Fluent Interface). Реализация тривиальна: нужно возвращать `$this` из методов, меняющих внутреннее состояние объекта. Например так:

```
class Human {
    private $firstName = '';
    private $lastName = '';

    public function setFirstName($first_name) {
        $this->firstName = $first_name;

        retrun $this;
    }

    public function setLastName($last_name) {
        $this->lastName = $last_name;

        retrun $this;
    }

    public function getFullName() {
        retrun $this->first_name . ' ' . $this->last_name;
    }
}

$john = new Human();

$john->setFirstName('John')
    ->setLastName('Doe')
    ->getFullName(); // 'John Doe'
```