# Что означает запись method()->anything в PHP?

Tags: php, laravel

Что в PHP означает запись `method()->anything`?

Например в Laravel (Eloquent) используется `$user = App\User::find(1)->user`, то есть обращаемся к классу User, его методу find с передачей параметра, а дальше что это за стрелка с user'ом? Свойство метода? Или как это называется и самое главное, как работает?

Comment: метод возвращает объект, обращаемся к его свойству.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Вызов методов объекта](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/524883/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b0)

Comment: и еще https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/737267/223826

Comment: получается, что записи `$user = App\User::find(1)->user` и `$user = new App\User::find(1)->user` эквивалентны?

Comment: вряд ли, не ясно что вы во втором примере вообще создаете.

Comment: Нет, не эквивалентны, по крайней мере потому, что здесь `$user = new App\User::find(1)->use` вообще синтаксическая ошибка будет.

Comment: `find` возвращает экземпляр класса, а не сам класс.